# How to add a <p> to a <div> on click with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have what I'm sure is a simple question.  I'm new to coding and just learning the basics of html/css/jquery.  I'm trying to load content to  by clicking .  Here is the code that I have, thank you ahead of time for your patience.

```
html:
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/javascript" src="wedding_projectJQuery.js"></link>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="wedding_projectStyles.css"/>
<title>Jason & Ashley Wedding</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Jason & Ashley's Wedding Website</h1>
    <div id="loader"></div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td id="date">Date</td>
            <td id="photos">Photos</td>
            <td id="donate">Donate</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
h1 {
    text-align:center;
}


#loader {
    text-align:center;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin:auto;
    height: 500px;
    width: 1000px;
}

table {
    padding:0px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    width:1000px;
    height:75px;
    margin:2px auto;
    clear:both;
}
td {
    width:250px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    text-align:center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
td:hover {
    background-color:green;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#date").click(function(){
        $("#loader").prepend('<p>The date is October 25th, 2014. The ceremony will begin when the fat lady sings.</p>');

    });

});
```

Comment: looks like you have not included the jQuery library

Comment: code looks good.. what is your problem..?

Comment: where is #date in your html??

Comment: he doesn't want to prepend but html

Comment: Add `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.js"></script>` and include your script after it using `<script src="wedding_projectJQuery.js"></script>

Comment: @C-link it's ID of TD

Comment: Go the basics. This will be a good start to you. You are using jQuery methods and you have not supplied the library at top of every script. If you just started then you must know what is the use of <link> and what is <script>.

Comment: why are you using tables? it's not the 90's

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include jQuery in your page and it should work.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wedding_projectJQuery.js"></script>
```

Also note that you need to use `<script></script>` instead of `<link />` to include your Javascript file

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PE64c/)**

Comment: Me too, doesn't make sense

Comment: Agreed with you @pjp.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I'm using the Code academy tutorials and they made no mention of linking to the library, lol.  I copied and pasted the first link, and changed my second one to a <script></script>.  I've also changed my function to insert the html as the second answer suggested, but it still doesnt display the text when I click the <td id="date">.

Comment: @user3572039 Did you check my demo? Please check if you're missing something?

Comment: @user3572039 Here is the demo that I put your whole HTML markup structure inside the Fiddle and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/4c4Ct/

Comment: Thank you for your help again.  It's working in the fiddle, idk why it isnt working when I run it in chrome from notepad++.  Is there a way to give you 'karma' for your help?  Or do I just click the ^ button next to your comment?  Edit: I cant upvote, so I just clicked the check mark.

Comment: @Felix after doing some research, it appears I have to include the http: in my code to run it locally, otherwise its run as a local file path.  Feels great and works great now, thank you all very much.

Answer (score 0):

After adding link to JQuery js library,

change your JQuery code from this:

```
$("#loader").prepend('<p>The date is October 25th, 2014. The ceremony will begin when the fat lady sings.</p>');
```

to this:

```
$("#loader").html('<p>The date is October 25th, 2014. The ceremony will begin when the fat lady sings.</p>');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I've added the library as per the answer above, version 1.11.0 and changed it to <script></script>.  I also changed .prepend to .html as you've suggested, and going back to my course tutorial, that was the way I should have done it in the first place.  But it still is not displaying the text when I click <td id="date">.